# How to display a True/False table

Tags: dataset, webmathematica

Below is my written program

```
list1 = {0, 1};

list2 = {{1}, {0, 1}, {0}};

For[i = 1, i <= Length[list1], i++, n = list1[[i]];

 For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++, list = list2[[j]];

  For[k = 1, k <= Length[list], k++, m = list[[k]];

   If[m == n, Break[]]

   ];

  If[m == n, Print[n, " True "], Print[n, " False "]]

  ]

 ]
```

My final outcome is

```
0 False 

0 True 

0 True 

1 True 

1 True 

1 False
```

But I want the answer in tabular form:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
0&False&True&True\\\hline
0&True&True&False\\\hline
\end{array}

Kindly help

Thank you in advance

Comment: It helps to describe what you want to do in plain English. It looks like you want to check if elements of `list1` are present in elements of `list2`. I would use `Outer[MemberQ, list2, list1, 1]` (`Transpose` it afterwards if necessary). I'd recommend [avoiding `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12) if you are a beginner.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be that you're not storing the outcomes of your tests anywhere -- you're just `Print`ing them. If you put them in a variable then there's a lot you can do to present that data however you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use a mixture of `Table`, `Cases` and `If` to produce the desired result.

Here are the lists

```
list1 = {0, 1};
list2 = {{1}, {0, 1}, {0}};
```

First let's apply `Cases` with a manual input where we test `list2` elements against zero.

```
Cases[list2, i_Integer -> If[i == 0, True, False], Infinity]
(* {False, True, False, True} *)
```

Next, rather than using 0, we will use the elements of `list1`. `Table` is helpful here.

```
out = Table[
  {i1,
   Cases[list2, i_Integer -> If[i == i1, True, False], Infinity]
   },
  {i1, list1}
  ]
(* {{0, {False, True, False, True}}, {1, {True, False, True, False}}} *)
```

The output was assigned to a variable `out` for subsequent processing.

The output is a nested list not quite the form that was requested.

`Flatten` is used to get the desired form.

```
Table[Flatten[sublist], {sublist, out}]
(* {{0, False, True, False, True}, {1, True, False, True, False}} *)
```

Finally `Grid` is used to place the result into a formatted table.

```
Grid[
 Table[Flatten[sublist], {sublist, out}],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The complete operation can be done in one fell swoop without the use of intermediate variables. However, I believe it is easier to follow (especially when creating the steps) to break it down into small pieces.

```
Grid[
 Table[Flatten[sublist],
  {sublist,
   Table[
    {i1,
     Cases[list2, i_Integer -> If[i == i1, True, False], Infinity]
     },
    {i1, list1}
    ]}
  ],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]